# mysql query wrong syntax

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this syntax, please:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT id, par, what, title,  inde 
                    FROM tmatria 
                    ORDER BY inde ASC 
                    where par = ' . $_SESSION["par"] . ';');
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where par = 0' at line 1

Comment: ORDER BY should be after the WHERE clause?

Comment: **RTM** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html and `WHERE` is a reserved word.which explains the **first** syntax error `near 'where` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Please read a SQL tutorial. The order of clauses is not flexible, and any tutorial should show the correct syntax.

Comment: Have you checked that `$_SESSION["par"]` doesn't contain `1=1'; delete from user; commit; --`?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong where position

```
'SELECT id, par, what, title,  inde 
 FROM tmatria 
 where par = '. $_SESSION["par"] . ' ORDER BY inde ASC ;'
```

Comment: why downvote without motivation ?

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER clause should come after WHERE clause

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, par, what, title,  inde FROM tmatria where par = '$_SESSION[par]' ORDER BY inde ASC");
```